# How do I insert a condition under while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner trying to learn python through MIT OpenCourseware. This problem is from [part B of problem set 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf). I understand the mathematical expression but I do not know how to write it out in code.
This is the problem:
Determine how long it will take to save enough
money to make the down payment for a house given the following assumptions:

- portion_down payment = 0.25 (25%)
- You start with a current savings of $0
- Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r = 0.04 (4%)
- Your salary increases by a certain percentage every 6 months (semi-annual rise)

Here is a test case:

Enter your starting annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .05
Enter the cost of your dream home: 500000
Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal: .03
Number of months: 142

Here is my code:

```
annual_salary = float(input('Annual Salary: '))
portion_saved = float(input('Portion saved (decimal): '))
total_cost = float(input('Total Cost of House: '))
semi_annual_rise = float(input('Semi-annual salary rise (decimal): '))
downp = float(0.25*total_cost)
current_savings = 0
monthly_savings = float(portion_saved*annual_salary/12)

ret = 1 + .04/12                       
rise = 1 + semi_annual_rise

n = 0

while current_savings < downp:
    for n in range(0,300,6): 
        monthly_savings = monthly_savings*(rise)
        current_savings = (current_savings + monthly_savings)*(ret)
        n += 1
print ('Number of months: ' + str(n))
```

Under the while loop, I am trying to increase the salary after 6, 12, 18 etc... months. But I dont know how to insert such a conditionI know it's wrong but I do not know how to correct it. Please help me!!

Comment: do you mean to overwrite your "n" variable? you declare it outside the loop, use it in the loop, and update it in the loop. maybe use 'm' for your number of months... and have m+=n in the loop.

Comment: The 'n' variable is the number of months. what i mean is the monthly savings should increase every 6 months and then subsequently i need to use that updated value to calculate the current savings. I dont know how to increase the monthly savings every 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the raise when *n%6 == 0* ...

```
...
n = 0
while current_savings < downp:
    n += 1
    if n % 6 == 0: #every six months
        monthly_savings = monthly_savings*(rise)
    current_savings = (current_savings + monthly_savings)*(ret)

...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Breaking the loop is a minor issue I had, but my main issue was fulfilling the condition stated in the problem. The monthly savings needs to increase by a certain percentage when n = 7, 13, 21... For example, if monthly savings is $1000 after 6 months ( i.e when n becomes 7), monthly savings should increase to $1030 (if the input semi-annual rise is .03). Hence the monthly savings (an input for calculation for current savings) should increase every 6 months while the current savings increases every month according to the formula above. Please help! Thank you.